# Using dummies in random effects model

Tags: categorical-data, panel-data, random-effects-model

When using dummy variables in a random effects model, how do I specify the model?

Assuming three dummies (e.g. for three industries):

- Do I treat it as three regressions, where I present a table with three columns for each of these dummies? (where all other variables are the same below in each column)
- Or do I have a table with only one column but the three dummy variables included below in the column?

EDIT: Particularly, what is the difference between the two ways of presenting the tables? Does it make sense to present first the table inlcuding all variables in one column, and present in a second step subsample analyses considering each dummy-category?

Thanks a lot for any prompt answer
bob

Comment: You can just use your dummies as you would in OLS. Include two of the three dummies in your model and then their coefficients are expressed relative to the base-industry (which is the one for which you did not include its dummy). Then you get a column vector of regression coefficients as usual. No need to fit separate models for each dummy. You cannot include all 3 dummies in the model.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This might sound trivial, but: I have three dummies (year, industry, credit rating), as well as interaction terms. Do I include them all in just one regression?

I thought, in order to provide a better layout for the reader of my paper, I make different tables, where I have multiple columns, as stated above? 
When I do that, does it change the meaning, or is is just a different layout, compared to including everything in one column?

thanks a lot